# How to manipulate imaginary part of matrixes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Look:

```
i=[1+1i 2+2i];
```

I want to do this:

```
imag(i)=10;
```

> Desired result:
>
> > `ans = [1+10i 2+10i]`

---

Also what about this:

```
m=[1+1i 2+2i 3+3i 4+4i 5+5i];
```

I want:

```
imag(m(real(m)>2)) = 10;
```

> Desired result:
>
> > `ans = [ 1+1i 2+2i 3+10i 4+10i 5+10i ]`

Unfortunately! These Desired result not happening in MATLAB.

Comment: What output do you want? this: `i=[1+2i   2+2i];` ?

Comment: Ok, thanks  ,corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick note, `i` is bad variable name when you are using complex numbers so I will substitute it with `vec`

```
vec=[1+1i 2+2i];
vec = complex(real(vec), 2);
```

---

**Edit**

With logical indexing:

```
idn = real(vec)>2;
vec(idn) = complex(real(vec(idn)), 10);
```

Comment: If i wanted to using "logical indexing" to assign imaginary part, Then what we must do??

Comment: both answer are correct & I confused to accept which one!! Maybe faster can be chosen but which one is faster?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd I have not benched marked the two methods but I believe that by calculating the indexing array `idn` in advance you only have to do it once, but there can be other slow/speedups which you might want to profile if you are after speed. As for which answer you should accept, just whichever one you feel is more suitable for your needs, look more elegant, it is really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you can do something like:

```
v = [1+1i 2+2i];
v = real(v) + 10i;
```

In the second case you can do something like:

```
v = [1+1i 2+2i 3+3i 4+4i 5+5i];
v(real(v)>2) = real(v(real(v)>2)) + 10i;
```

As far as I know, is not possible to reference real and imaginary parts of a complex number in Matlab as if they are seperate variables without a function call to real and/or imaginary.

Comment: both answer are correct & I confused to accept which one!! Maybe faster can be chosen but which one is faster?